# Auto email responding

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using the below code to submit form information to my email account but i also want it to send a confirmation email to the sender. I like to add this message for automatic response
`

Thanks for your interest "name of the sender"!

This is just a quick note to let you know we have received your form and will respond as soon as we can.

Best,

Marvin

` can you check my code how could I add the code and execute it well?

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$status = array(
    'type' => 'success',
    'message' => 'Application Sent！'
);


$name           =   @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
$address        =   @trim(stripslashes($_POST['address']));
$email          =   @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$mobile         =   @trim(stripslashes($_POST['mobile']));

$email_form = $email;
$email_to = 'mrvn.acosta@gmail.com';

$body = '[name]'     . $name     .  "\n\n" .

        '[address]'  . $address  .  "\n\n" .

        '[email]'    . $email    .  "\n\n" .

        '[mobile]'   . $mobile;


mb_language("Japanese");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$success = mb_send_mail($email_to, 'Application', $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die; ?>
```

there is no problem with this code, I just like recoding for the auto-responding email when this form is successfully sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append below code at bottom to send email to the sender as well.

```
// Email to Sender (Without HTML/CSS)

$sender_email = $email;
$admin_email = 'mrvn.acosta@gmail.com';

$message = "Thanks for your interest".$name."\n\n";

$message .= "This is just a quick note to let you know we have received your 
form and will respond as soon as we can.\n\n";

$message .= "Best,\n\n";
$message .= "Marvin\n\n";

mb_language("Japanese");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$success2 = mb_send_mail($sender_email, 'Thanks', $message, 'From: 
<'.$admin_email.'>');


// Email to Sender (With HTML/CSS)

$sender_email = $email;
$admin_email = 'mrvn.acosta@gmail.com';

$header = "From: ".$admin_email." \n";
$header.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";

$message = '<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            <!--
                .style2 {
                font-size: 11px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                color:#666666;

                }
                .style3 {
                text-decoration: none;
                font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 11px;
                color:#666666;
                }
                -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="600" border="0" align="center" style="border:#EFEFEF 
5px solid; padding:5px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-
size:11px; color:#666666">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" 
cellspacing="6">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="style3">Thanks for your interest 
'.$name.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="style3">This is just a quick note to 
let you know we have received your 
form and will respond as soon as we can.</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="style3">Best,<br>
                                Marvin
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>';

mb_language("Japanese");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$success2 = mb_send_mail($sender_email, 'Thanks', $message, $header);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you so much, it works... really appreciated. ^___^ but 1 thing how could I change this ".$sender_email." to the name of the sender?

Comment: use $name in place of $sender_email in message. Check my updated code.

Comment: I hope you will give upvote and accept both my answers :) Happy to help further.

Comment: got it ^_^ I change the code from .$sender_email. to .$name. ^___^

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159364/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-marvin-acosta).

Comment: thank you @Amit really appreciated, God blessed ^___^