# Not echoing the unused text input

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form with a set of question field to fill-out the user, but some of the questions were usually not answered. after the form was done there is a NEXT button to continue and proceed to the confirmation page, where the user will double check his/her information to the fill-outed form.

QUESTION: Is it possible not to echoing the unused text input field?

[image]

Here is the sample code for Form

```
<!-- Contact Form Wrap Starts -->
<div class="contact-form-wrap">
    <h5 class="sub-heading-1 text-center-xs">Application Form</h5>
<!-- Form Starts -->
<div class="status alert alert-success contact-status"></div>

<form action="confirmation.php" class="contactform"  method="get" 
 name="contactform" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">

<!-- Last Name Filed Starts -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" 
                     id="lname" required="required" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
        </div>

 <!-- First Name Filed start -->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" 
                    id="fname" required="required" placeholder="Firs Name">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <!-- Contact Filed Starts -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="mobile">Mobile No</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" 
                 id="mobile" required="required" placeholder="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-medium animation" value="NEXT" style="margin-left: 0px">
```

and here is the code for the confimation.php

```
<div class="status alert alert-success contact-status1"></div>  
    <form id="main-contact-form1"  style="background-color: #f0f8ff; padding: 20px;" class="contact-form1" name="contact-form1" method="post" action="sendappli.php" role="form">   

<!-- Name start -->                 
    <div class="label-field-pair">
        <label>Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id='name' name='name' value='<?php 
             echo $_GET["lname"]; ?> <?php echo $_GET["fname"]; ?>' />
    </div>

<!-- Contact start -->        
    <div class="label-field-pair">
        <label>Contact Numer</label>
            <input class="form-control" id='name' name='name' value='<?php 
             echo $_GET["mobile"]; ?> />
    </div>
```

Let's say the Contact No input field are not used.

Comment: Yes, it is possible if that is your question.

Comment: if so. how could I execute that? ^^

Comment: @MarvinAcosta You need to add condition with every set of your field code in your confirmation page. Check contact code I update for you in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `if condition` to check whether your fields are having any value or not. Based on that condition you will show that in your `confirmation page`.

Like if the `contact number input field` is not used or user not entered any data in `contact field` then you need to update your `contact code` in below way.

```
<?php if(!empty($_GET["mobile"])){ ?>
    <!-- Contact start -->        
    <div class="label-field-pair">
        <label>Contact Numer</label>
        <input class="form-control" id='mobile' name='mobile' value='<?php 
         echo $_GET["mobile"]; ?> />
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Or

```
<?php if(isset($_GET["mobile"]) && $_GET["mobile"]!=""){ ?>
    <!-- Contact start -->        
    <div class="label-field-pair">
        <label>Contact Numer</label>
        <input class="form-control" id='mobile' name='mobile' value='<?php 
         echo $_GET["mobile"]; ?> />
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

You need to update all your other fields code like `Name` in your `confirmation page` in the above way.

Hope it works!

Comment: You are welcome Marvin. Don't forget to upvote and accept my answer :)

Comment: sure. but can I have another favor? I have also a problem using auto email response, can you check my code here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925780/auto-email-responding/47325132?noredirect=1#comment81671878_47325132

Comment: Sure! I will check and get back to you.

Comment: Check I have answered there. Hope it resolve your issue.

Comment: Hope you will give upvote and accept my answers now. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery to assign a hidden attribute to the inputs if its text is empty.

Would give example if you provide some code to work with.

Comment: hello @Yorki please see the updated post thank you^^